# Trouble changing android-minSdkLevel on Ionic project

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, sdk

Well...

Once i've set the android-minSdkLevel on my ionic project and this worked, but now this isn't working...

I've set

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="19" />
```

And when I run `ionic platform add android` it is always adding android@5.2.2 instead of android@4.4.2(api level 19)...

I've found this at the end of my config.xml `<engine name="android" spec="~5.2.2" />` and tried to use spec="~4.4.2" but this didn't work too... Cordova returns me that 4.4.2 is not an available version.

Comment: Did you change value in `..\IonicApp\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml` also? - `

Comment: No, i didnt... But config.xml should generate this file with these specs, right?

Comment: Yes, it should but sometimes things go wrong.